# sysfs: Correspondence between modules and drivers?

Tags: linux, drivers, kernel-modules, hardware, sysfs

In sysfs, one can find which driver is handling a device. For example, the following shows that the driver handling the device `led0` is called `leds-gpio`.

```
pi@raspberrypi:/sys/devices/platform/leds/leds/led0/device $ ls -l
 ...
 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Apr 18 10:58 driver -> ../../../bus/platform/drivers/leds-gpio
 ...
```

One can find `leds-gpio.c` in the source code of the Linux kernel. However, one cannot find any module with name `leds-gpio`, neither through `lsmod` nor in `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)`.

How can we know which module contains a given driver, say the `leds-gpio` driver in this example?